# File_get_content error

Tags: php, curl

I have tried hosting it on a VPS/web Host and some VPS it works my script and some it gives this error:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://xip.xxxxx.org/xxxx/../aaaada23.php?user=rawr&host=127.0.0.1&port=3074&time=10&ip=127.0.0.1&power=1)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed
>   to open stream: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to
>   respond. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\login\boot.php on line
>   163 Script bad error

Why do I get that error? Could it be DNS?

Comment: It works in your browser? You are aware that `127.0.0.1` will be something else to the remote server than it is to you?

Comment: A DNS error would be "no such host". "Failed to connect" implies that it got an IP address, but could not succesffully open a connection.

Comment: Fixed, it was DNS issue apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means that the domain you're trying to reach is down, unreachable.

it could also mean that the networking/sockets are down on your machine.

Probably winsock error: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924071.aspx

Comment: Not necessarily. More often than not, this is a firewall issue

Comment: It was DNS problem, now fixed. Thanks. It fixed itself :)